# Accessing DB during Application start

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have Xamarin Forms solution and in App.xaml.cs I would like to read from database (SQLite). In method OnStart(), if I try to create table (if it doesn't exist):

```cs
await connection.CreateTableAsync<User>();
```

exception is thrown. I can't catch this exception with try/catch.

Is it possible to access database from App.xaml.cs?

Comment: What is the Exception that you get? What does it say?

Comment: I can't catch this exception with try/catch. Only Dialog is shown with text "An unhandled exception occured."

Comment: Check the application output or try something else. With this information it is very hard for us to determine what is going on.